# Parse a xml attribute depending on child content

Tags: php, xml, parsing, match

I load an external xml file containing user metas looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user_information>
<user url="http://usersweb.com">
<name>Arnold</name>
<lastname>
<name>Arnoldson</name>
</lastname>
<age>42</age>
</user>
<user url="http://anotheruserweb.com">
<name>Arnold</name>
<lastname>
<name>Arichson</name>
</lastname>
<age>42</age>
</user>
And so on....
</user_information>
```

I know the formatting with

```
<lastname>
```

is really stupid, but i can't modify the source.

I want to load in the "url"-attribute from

```
<user>
```

, but only if

```
<name>
```

and

```
<lastname>
```

matches the name values i have stored in my own user database.

I know how to parse the rest of it with PHP, but just the matching sequence seems difficult to me. Any help appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**
Since i can not give you the source XML, i found a similar code structure in the Spotify Metadata API. We can laborate with the returning XML-file from the track search "Domino Dancing": [ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=Domino Dancing](http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=Domino%20Dancing)

It has the exactly same structur, excepts it use other words. The returning file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<tracks xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns="http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1"> 
<opensearch:Query role="request" startPage="1" searchTerms="Domino Dancing"/> 
<opensearch:totalResults>39</opensearch:totalResults> 
<opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex> 
<opensearch:itemsPerPage>100</opensearch:itemsPerPage> 
<track href="spotify:track:2aV5vCNH5tOOe0GGKqfx5Z"> 
<name>Domino dancing</name> 
<artist href="spotify:artist:2ycnb8Er79LoH2AsR5ldjh"> 
<name>Pet Shop Boys</name> 
</artist> 
<id type="isrc">GBAYE0301704</id> 
<album href="spotify:album:0BAfuhzkGjckMhsL2gVbzR"> 
<name>Ultimate</name> 
<released>2010</released> 
<availability> 
<territories>AT BE CH CY CZ DE DK EE ES FI FR GB GR HR HU IE IT LT LU NL NO PL PT RO SE SI SK</territories> 
</availability> 
</album> 
<track-number>7</track-number> 
<length>258.106000</length> 
<popularity>0.57092</popularity> 
</track> 
<track href="spotify:track:4mVLzFbc3gaCoWCEENLouc"> 
<name>Domino Dancing</name> 
<artist href="spotify:artist:2ycnb8Er79LoH2AsR5ldjh"> 
<name>Pet Shop Boys</name> 
</artist> 
<id type="isrc">GBAYE8800056</id> 
<album href="spotify:album:0Jt2LzWgtGxy3GZH5i2Kcy"> 
<name>Discography - Complete Singles Collection</name> 
<released>1991</released> 
<availability> 
<territories>AT BE CH CY CZ DE DK EE ES FI FR GB GR HR HU IE IT LT LU NL NO PL PT RO SE SI SK</territories> 
</availability> 
</album> 
<track-number>10</track-number> 
<length>258.333000</length> 
<popularity>0.56159</popularity> 
</track> 
<track href="spotify:track:72kgJ1brMxxeDiPNdH6qqW"> 
<name>Viva la vida/Domino dancing</name> 
<artist href="spotify:artist:2ycnb8Er79LoH2AsR5ldjh"> 
<name>Pet Shop Boys</name> 
</artist> 
<id type="isrc">GBCEW0900049</id> 
<album href="spotify:album:4DZfMTDyBwnJQ0k1PaT6U4"> 
<name>Pet Shop Boys Christmas</name> 
<released>2009</released> 
<availability> 
<territories>AT BE CH CY CZ DE DK EE ES FI FR GB GR HR HU IE IT LT LU NL NO PL PT RO SE SI SK</territories> 
</availability> 
</album> 
<track-number>4</track-number> 
<length>333.507000</length> 
<popularity>0.51961</popularity> 
</track>
</tracks>
```

If we pretend that
user_information=tracks
user=track
url=href
lastname=artist.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT2:**
I solved it using Xpath Document and namespaces. Thank you all for trying!

Answer (score 1):

This XPATH selects the `@url` for Arnold Archison:

```
/user_information/user[name='Arnold' and lastname/name='Arichson']/@url
```

---

**EDIT**

> Two questions about your solution: 1.
>   Can i use xpath with
>   simplexml_load_file instead of
>   simplexmlelement? 2. Can i replace the
>   values Arnold Arichson with a variable
>   like $users_firstname and
>   $users_lastname=

I'm not a PHP guy, but I believe that you should be able to do something like this (you might need to concatenate the XPATH string differently, or may not need to escape the single quotes, not sure):

```
<?php

$first = "Arnold";
$last = "Arichson";

$userInfo =  simplexml_load_file('http://your.website.com/user_information.xml');

foreach ($userInfo->xpath("/user_information/user[name=\'$first\' and lastname/name=\'$last\']/@url") as $url) {
  echo "<h2>" . $url . "</h2>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Two questions about your solution:
1. Can i use xpath with simplexml_load_file instead of simplexmlelement?
2. Can i replace the values Arnold Arichson with a variable like $users_firstname and $users_lastname=

Comment: I think so. I've updated my answer using the code from this article as a template: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-simplexml.html#N10228

Comment: When i try this solution, the server throws me "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". Do i something wrong? Just copy-pasted it.

Comment: I hadn't tested the code, just adopted it from the article. It may not like how I tried escaping the single quotes in the XPATH. You may need to concatenate the XPATH string like this: `foreach ($userInfo->xpath("/user_information/user[name='" . $first . "' and lastname/name='" . $last . "']/@url") as $url)`

Comment: I still gets the above error. Does xpath accept that you include variables in the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);
foreach ($xml->user as $value) {
   if ($value->name == $x && $value->lastname->name == $y) {
      $attr = $value->attributes();
      echo $attr['url'];
   }
}
```

This will load the xml string into a simple xml object, then compare the node values, and if they match your desired name (`$x` and `$y`), print the url. You can also load an xml file instead of string to create the `simplexml` object if needed. see `simplexml` documentation for more info.

ADDITION

Using string (tested and works):

```
<?php
    $xml_input = <<<XML
<user_information> <user url="http://usersweb.com"> <name>Arnold</name> <lastname> <name>Arnoldson</name> </lastname> <age>42</age> </user> <user url="http://anotheruserweb.com"> <name>Arnold</name> <lastname> <name>Arichson</name> </lastname> <age>42</age> </user></user_information>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_input); 
foreach ($xml->user as $value) {
    if ($value->name == 'Arnold' && $value->lastname->name == 'Arnoldson') {
        $attr = $value->attributes();
        echo $attr['url'];
    }
} 
?>
```

Using file (should work exact same):

```
<?php
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_file_path, 0, true); 
    foreach ($xml->user as $value) {
        if ($value->name == 'Arnold' && $value->lastname->name == 'Arnoldson') {
            $attr = $value->attributes();
            echo $attr['url'];
        }
    } 
?>
```

In the object construct, I added the arguments 0 and true, which allows you to use a file path for the first argument instead of a string. But yes, you could also use the load file function as well.

Comment: Seems to be a nice solution, but can i use it with simplexml_load_file? I'm not familiar with simplexmlelement. Cause i didn't got it to work...

Comment: edited above to show more example code (working example for string and for filepath).

Comment: if this solution works for you, please select the check mark next to my answer. thanks!

Comment: Im sorry, but i could not make this work. Am i doing something wrong? Just copy-paste.

Comment: i mean, you will have to set $xml_file_path to equal whatever the actual xml file's file path is... and you will have to make sure all of the node paths are correct... you can't just "copy-paste"... you will have to try to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Okey, bad description by me! Ofcourse i set the path to my actual file.

Comment: what happens? is there error? what happens when you vardump the $xml after creating it? can you leave a link to the actual xml file you are using?

Comment: does simplexml_load_file($filepath) return false?